# Get the root node from leaf in Oracle on the basis of current date

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to identify the root node on the base of leaf and the current date.

I have a table **tree_table** with data

```
  child_node    parent_node    start_date     end_date
           A              B    1/1/2009       31/12/2050
           B              C    1/1/2009       31/12/2010
           C              D    1/1/2009       31/12/2050
           D              E    1/1/2009       31/12/2050
```

to fetch the root node i am using the Query

```
select parent_node from(
SELECT parent_node
FROM tree_table exp
where connect_by_isleaf = 1 and sysdate between start_date and end_Date
START WITH child_node = 'A'
CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_node = child_node order by rownum desc)  where rownum=1
```

But the problem here is that as you can see the second record doesn't satisfy the condition. Stil I am getting the output

```
Output: E
```

Which is incorrect i was supposed to get the **Output B**

Can you please help me out. What i am doing wrong in my query.
I am using Oracle database.

Comment: is the end_date for child_node = B supposed to be 2010, or should it be 2050 like the others?

Comment: It should be 2010 @Boneist

Comment: and if you move `sysdate between start_date and end_date` to be an and on the connect by?  (may be an order of operation issue)

Comment: xQbert - that is the correct answer, so please post it as an Answer.

Comment: To expand on xQbert's answer: the CONNECT BY operation happens before the WHERE clause, not after it. The way you wrote the query, if the root node satisfies the date condition, it will be returned, or else nothing will be returned. What you do want, instead, is that the date condition be required at each node; to do so, include it in CONNECT BY. For analogy, think of where you need to put certain conditions in an outer join (in the ON clause vs. the WHERE clause).

Comment: Thank you, Experts, for all your knowledge. @xQbert. It is working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tested this but I believe you have an order of operation issue.  The where clause occurs after the hierarchy is traversed; when I believe you want the date condition to be part of the hierarchy traverse.

I think you want the date check to occur as part of the connect by so it stops processing the hierarchy once the date condition is encountered.

```
  SELECT paren_node 
  FROM (SELECT parent_dode
        FROM tree_table exp
        WHERE connect_by_isleaf = 1 
        START WITH child_node = 'A'
        CONNECT BY PRIOR pared_node = child_node 
                     AND sysdate between start_date and end_Date
        ORDER BY rownum desc)  
   WHERE rownum = 1
```